# "Anti-merge" two data frames -- find the observations that appear in one but not in the other

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Is there such a command? In STATA, when two datasets are merge there is a flag variable (called `_m`) that indicates whether a observation appears in both or only one dataset. Based on this flag, the user would be able to select observations unique to one dataset.

Comment: Maybe `anti_join` from `dplyr`? No flagging, but does return just rows unique to the one dataset.

Comment: @aosmith That works perfectly. By the way, is `dplyr` join a perfect substitute for base `merge`?

Comment: You should add a reproducible example. I think that a `!key_A %in% key_b` should do it.

Comment: @Heisenberg base `merge` will only merge two data frames at a time, but you can easily write a function to join n data frames: `f <- function(...) Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), list(...))`, but `join_all` is a nice function if you already are using the plyr package

Comment: actually I would do `f <- function(l, ...) Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, ...), l)` where `l` is a list of data frames and `...` are arguments you can pass to `merge`

Comment: @Heisenberg Not yet, but possibly once `outer_join` and `right_join` join the ranks: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/96

Comment: @rawr Thanks for your help, but I'm not sure how your answer (about merging multiple data frames) is relevant to this question. I've found @aosmith's recommendation of `anti_join` from `dplyr` to be a perfect solution.

Comment: If you look not five inches above this post you will see "By the way, is dplyr join a perfect substitute for base merge" which you wrote..

Comment: @rawr I appreciate your help regardless, but just so I understand: isn't it true that `Reduce` can be used for both dplyr join and base merge to merge multiple data frames? How is this a differentiating factor between them? I was asking @aosmith whether there's something merge can do but join can't (so that I can switch to join entirely).

Comment: I was pointing out the limitation of base merge which I gave a solution to so that you could use it with the same functionality of third party packages. There is nothing wrong with using join_all or anti_join for everything you do.